# Postgres Throwing invalid input syntax for a column that allows Null Values

Tags: database, postgresql, sql-insert, postgresql-14

I am trying to load data from a csv file into a postgres database using psycopg2

This is the table schema:

```
Column               |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
---------------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 implementation_type | character varying(25)  |           | not null | 
 file_type           | character varying(7)   |           | not null | 
 loop                | character varying(10)  |           |          | 
 segment_name        | character varying(10)  |           |          | 
 segment_desc        | character varying(255) |           |          | 
 element_name        | character varying(255) |           |          | 
 element_no          | character varying(10)  |           |          | 
 data_type           | character varying(5)   |           |          | 
 requirment          | character(1)           |           |          | 
 repeat              | character varying(3)   |           |          | 
 min                 | integer                |           |          | 
 max                 | integer                |           |          | 
 possible_values     | character varying(255) |           |          |
```

```
Error : Error: invalid input syntax for type integer: ""
LINE 16: ...', 'REFERENCE IDENTIFIER', 'REF04', '', 'O', '1', '', '', ''...
```

It throws error for column min

Note:

- This is the first min row with min having a null value.
- possible_values has had null values in some row previously but that is inserted without any error.

This is the python code that inserts data.

```
for row in data:
            sql = """
                INSERT INTO segment_data (
                    IMPLEMENTATION_TYPE,
                    FILE_TYPE,
                    Loop,
                    Segment_Name,
                    Segment_Desc,
                    Element_Name,
                    Element_No,
                    Data_Type,
                    Requirment,
                    Repeat,
                    Min,
                    Max,
                    Possible_Values
                ) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);
            """
            cursor.execute(sql, tuple(row))
        connection.commit()
```

Comment: A NULL value is different from an empty string. So you have to use `VALUES (NULL)` rather than `VALUES ('')` if you want to insert a NULL value. Empty strings are no valid integers.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz, Is there any way to input nullvalues in the csv file. Otherwise the code to load the data will be too long. I will have to consider a lot of cases for different combinations of columns with null values.

Comment: You are the one parsing the CSV file. How you treat empty columns is your decision.

Comment: Understood. Solved It. Not sure if this is the best way. But this is how we did it.
I am replacing all empty string with a integer. Then just altering those values to NULL in the db. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to insert an empty string '' into a column of type integer, especially the "min" column, which is declared as an integer in your table schema. This is the reason of the issue you are experiencing. For an integer column, PostgreSQL treats an empty string as an invalid input because it doesn't automatically convert it to a NULL value.

Before adding the data into the database, you should change empty strings in your Python code to NULL values to fix this problem. To do this, a conditional statement might be used. Here's how to change your code to handle this situation:

```
for row in data:
    # Convert empty strings to None for integer columns
    for i in range(len(row)):
        if row[i] == '':
            row[i] = None

    sql = """
        INSERT INTO segment_data (
            IMPLEMENTATION_TYPE,
            FILE_TYPE,
            Loop,
            Segment_Name,
            Segment_Desc,
            Element_Name,
            Element_No,
            Data_Type,
            Requirment,
            Repeat,
            Min,
            Max,
            Possible_Values
        ) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);
    """
    cursor.execute(sql, tuple(row))
connection.commit()
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. This is a better way to do the same thing.
Thank you